# There is something wrong in my code it only reads first if statement and the else if does not?

Tags: c#, if-statement

This is C# program I have a problem in this line of code:

I input numbers greater that or equal 400`=` it runs
I input numbers less that or equal 500`=` it runs
I input numbers between 400 and 500 ex 401 to 499`=` it runs
I empty input= erorr
I input letters= erorr

Take note that I run the code that wil only accept integer separately it runs
and also the code that will not accept empty input it also runs

What do you think is wrong?

```
        int parsedValue;
        if (int.Parse(txtVacate.Text) <= 400 || int.Parse(txtVacate.Text) >= 500)
            MessageBox.Show("Romms provided is not vacant or does not exist at all.");

        else if (txtVacate.Text == " ")
            MessageBox.Show("You provide empty");

        else if (!int.TryParse(txtVacate.Text, out parsedValue))
            MessageBox.Show("Please provide right info");
        else
        {
            MySqlConnection connection = null;
            string hostname = "localhost";
            string database = "aparece_hoteldb";
            string username = "root";
            string password = "";
            connection = new MySqlConnection("host=" + hostname +
                                            ";database=" + database +
                                            ";username=" + username +
                                            ";password=" + password + ";");


            string table = "reservations";
            string query = "DELETE FROM reservations WHERE RoomNumber = " + txtVacate.Text;
            connection.Open();
            MySqlDataAdapter da_res = null;
            DataSet ds_res = null;
            ds_res = new DataSet();
            da_res = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, connection);
            da_res.Fill(ds_res, table);
            MessageBox.Show("Room" + " " + txtVacate.Text + " " + "is now Vacant please reload!");
            dataGridView2.DataSource = ds_res.Tables[table];
            this.Close();
```

Comment: I am new in C# programming language!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid your logic is wrong. If `txtVacate.Text` doesn't contain an integer, your code will blow up. This is the correct order for evaluating your different conditions.

```
int parsedValue = 0;
bool isValid = int.TryParse(txtVacate.Text, out parsedValue));
if (txtVacate.Text == " ") // Better: if (txtVacate.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
{
    MessageBox.Show("You provide empty");
}
else if (!isValid)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please provide right info");
}
else if (parsedValue <= 400 || parsedValue >= 500)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Romms provided is not vacant or does not exist at all.");   
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first if statement uses

```
int.Parse(txtVacate.Text)
```

For empty or non-numeric (text) values, this will throw a FormatException, so your 'else if' cases will never be evaluated.

You should use TryParse, instead of Parse in your first 'if', or catch the FormatException and handle it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify this a few steps.

First, check to make sure the input is not null, whitespaces, or empty.

If there is a value, parse it to make sure it is a numerical value.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtVacate.Text))
{
    in parsedValue = 0;
    bool isValid = int.TryParse(txtVacate.Text, out parsedValue));

    if (isValid) 
    {
        if (parsedValue <= 400 || parsedValue >= 500)
            MessageBox.Show("Romms provided is not vacant or does not exist at all.");
        else 
        {
            // main stuff here
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please provide right info");
    }
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("You provide empty");
}
```

While complex, this should properly handle all use cases